# Can you export a .midi file with a sf2 sound font file in python using fluid synth?

Tags: terminal, midi, fluidsynth, soundfont

Using fluidsynth, can you open a midi file with a soundfont (sf2) and export the file into a .wav or a mp3 or some sort of flattened audio file?

I know you can use the -T flag which seems to export into a specified type of file but when I run `fluidsynth -T wav GeneralUser.sf2 composition.midi` it does not export anything when I quit the program.

Answer (score 1):

Given a midi file, you can create a wav file from it with a given sound font. In my Ubuntu bash shell I do it by typing below:

```
fluidsynth /opt/sf2/Chateau_Grand-v2.1.sf2 -F /tmp/test.wav /tmp/test.midi
```

The recorded output is `/tmp/test.wav`. I have my personal MIDI recording using a **Korg microKEY 49** and converted it into a `record.wav` I uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oqmAUSbWlMmrzn2Ujo_yNEtLtRfbUDGd?fbclid=IwAR2FEwdBDfTza0ru76FpLQQdDKPWkP1SS-jInzC0iksM6gOPFzRubiY1VyE)